# React native with agora not working RtcEngine. setEnableSpeakerPhone()

Tags: react-native, agora.io

I am making a project with react-native-agora. In my old android Ver5(lolipop) working nice but in my new android vivo Ver8.1.0(oreo) not working.

I used to toggle between speakerphone and receiver as agora docs says,

```
  rtcEngine.setEnableSpeakerphone(true) -> for speakerphone
  rtcEngine.setEnableSpeakerphone(false) -> for receiver
```

This my following code for initializing RtcEngine

```
const rtcEngine = await RtcEngine.create(appId)
rtcEngine.addListener('UserJoined', (uid, elapsed) => { })
rtcEngine.addListener('UserMuteAudio', (uid, reason) => { })
rtcEngine.addListener('UserOffline', (uid, reason) => { })
rtcEngine.joinChannel(appId, channelName, null, 0)
rtcEngine.muteLocalAudioStream(mute)
rtcEngine.setEnableSpeakerphone(speaker)
```

This for how i am toggling the values

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.footerBtnContainer} onPress={ () => { setSpeaker(!speaker); }} >
    <IonIcon name="volume-mute-outline" style={speaker?styles.footIconOn:styles.footIconOff} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This my state for changing values

```
 const [ speaker, setSpeaker]          = useState(false);
```

And my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.2",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.11.1",
"agora-rn-uikit": "^3.0.1",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"react-native-agora": "^3.1.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
"react-native-mo-fs": "^0.1.24",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
"react-native-screens": "^2.12.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0"
 },
```

Answer (score 2):

The `setEnableSpeakerphone` method needs to be called each time to switch between the speaker and earpiece. I'm assuming you're trying to change between them using the state value. With your code it only gets executed once when you initialize the RtcEngine. When you flip the state on button press the function isn't executed - so there's no effect. You'll have to edit your code to call `setEnableSpeakerphone` each time. I'd suggest defining a function as follows:

```
const toggleDevice = async () => {
  await this._engine?.setEnableSpeakerphone(!speaker);
  setSpeaker(speakerValue => !speakerValue)
};
```

And editing your button to call the toggleDevice function - `onPress={toggleDevice}`